# Homotopy invariant line integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Consider a smooth function $g: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb C$ and define a function $$f(x,y):=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \overline{g}(x,y)-\frac{\partial}{\partial y} g(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \overline{g}(x,y)$$

where $g$ denotes the complex conjugate.

Is it true that if we integrate $f$ over the boundary $\partial A$ of an annulus $A$ that this integral vanishes, i.e.

$$\int_{\partial A} f(z) \ dz=0? $$

Please let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Did you try a (nonconstant) example, like $g(x, y) = x + iy$?

Comment: @JohnHughes I tried some examples, but not this particular one and so far did not get a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, $g(x,y) = x \cos y + ix \sin y$ is a counterexample.
$$f = (\cos y + i\sin y)(-x\sin y - i x\cos y) - (-x\sin y + ix\cos y)(\cos y - i\sin y) = -2ix$$
Evaluating the loop integral of this function about the circle $|z| = 1$ yields
$$\oint_{|z| = 1}f(z)\, dz = \int_0^{2\pi}2e^{it}\cos t\, dt = 2\pi$$
Evaluating the loop integral of this function about the circle $|z| = 2$ yields
$$\oint_{|z| = 2}f(z)\, dz = \int_0^{2\pi}8e^{it}\cos t\,dt = 8\pi \neq 2\pi$$

Comment: I am not claiming it is zero, I am claiming it does not depend on the radius of the circle in your case.